# How to get the path of a pdf report downloaded in a browser in Odoo 13?

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, odoo-12, odoo-13

I have a method which prints a pdf report and downloads it to the OS in Odoo 13 upon clicking a button. Now, I need to get (access) the path (where it is downloaded) of this report (file) and store it in ir_attachment table of Odoo. After storing the file (report) path then I want to have a button which fetch this report from it's the path stored in database and shows it in browser for a portal user in website module. I searched a lot but could not find anyway to do it. Can anyone help me if is it possible and if yes how?

Answer (score 0):

Have you check with this method `get_portal_url(report_type='pdf', download=True)`?

Comment: Could you please tell me where should I use this method to get the url of the printed report?

Comment: Please find this in odoo's addons  you'll get the Idea.